# In magento 2.4.* we found "{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception",..." error after setup: upgrade

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, setup-upgrade

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception"[image]

Answer (score 3):

go to "Cache Management" and first disable all cache and after enable it so this error is remove from setup:upgrade comand list

[image]

Run THis Comman on Terminal:

**curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'**

Restart Elasticsearch

if not working please do below step
run command
**1-> `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'`**
**2-> `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`**

> After running the above codes, run below mentioned commands

–

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thank you, worked for me!